# Cache a 15MB filestream response from WCF at client side

Tags: asp.net, wcf, session, filestream, viewstate

I'm getting nearly 15MB of FileStream object response from WCF service to the client. what is the best way to cache it at client end as I have multiple operations to be done like extracting the content and processing the stream.
ViewState and sessions might increase the page size.

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient();
var s = client.GetDocument(path);
```

GetDocument Method returns the fileStream, once the response is received it is displayed in email format with links to attachments. On attachment click ,it should be retrieved from the filestream only.

Comment: Can you show the code of your service-client?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: It's unclear from your question what you are hoping to achieve. Are you talking about caching a service response?

Comment: @Tom Yes exactly, i need to hold the response